# Casting HashMap Key Iterator to List Iterator

Tags: java, collections

I need to access the HashMap key elements much like a linked list with prev and curr pointers to do some comparisons. I typecasted the HashMap Key Iterator to List Iterator to access current as well as previous key elements. Below is the code

```
HashMap<Node,Double> adj;
ListIterator<Node> li = (ListIterator<Node>) adj.keySet().iterator();

while (li.hasNext()) {
    if (li.hasPrevious()) {
                prev = li.previous();
    } else {
                prev = null;
    }
...
}
```

But I am getting the below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator cannot be cast to java.util.ListIterator
at Types$AdjList.makeConnected(Types.java:357)
at Main.main(Main.java:89)
```

Is there some way that I can typecast a HashMap Key Iterator to List Iterator to solve my purpose. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Somnath

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `iterator` of `adj.keySet()` cannot be casted to a `ListIterator` because its keys set (**returned by the `keySet()`**) method is not a `list`, but a `Set`. Thus it doesn't have an order.

You can try to use `LinkedHashMap` for this purpose or create a new `List` instance from the `keySet` like this

```
List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>(adj.keySet());
```

and then perform the desired manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
HashMap<Node,Double> adj;
Iterator<Node> li = (Iterator<Node>) adj.keySet().iterator();

while (li.hasNext()) {
    if (li.hasPrevious()) {
                prev = li.previous();
    } else {
                prev = null;
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public HashMap JsonToMap(JSONObject js,HashMap hm){
         @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
         Iterator<String> nameItr =  js.keySet().iterator();
         while(nameItr.hasNext()) {
             String name = nameItr.next();
             hm.put(name, js.get(name).toString());
         }
        return hm;
    }
```